# The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows-server-2012

espero que se encuentren bien.

Les comento que tengo desarrollada una app con net4.8 la cual utiliza WebClient y HttpClient para descargar imágenes desde una url.
La aplicación funciona bien, pero cuando la instalo en el servidor (windows server 2012 R2), me arroja el siguiente error:

```
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

Lo extraño es que funcionaba perfectamente y de un día para otro comenzó a arrojar ese error.

La instale en el IIS de mi equipo y en el IIS de otras 2 máquinas virtuales y todo ok.
Pero en el server de producción muestra ese error y es solo en ese servidor que ocurre eso.

Esta aplicación no usa certificados digitales, así que está descartada esa posibilidad.

¿Que podría estar ocurriendo en el servidor?, de antemano, les agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Podría estar relacionado con la version de TLS? Echa un ojo a [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34716551/579895)

Answer (score 0):

yo tuve un problema similar cuando implemente el uso de un webservice de cotizaciones de un banco, y lo resolvió de la manera que te mando Pikoh a revisar, pero también en esa investigación encontré esto:
"After installing one of the following Windows Updates, Windows may cancel SSL connections if the public key length of the certificate is less than 2048 bytes:
Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7:
KB3172605
KB3175024
KB3185278
KB3185330
KB3192391
Windows Server 2012 R2 and Windows 8:

KB3174644
KB3185331
KB3188743"

,porque veo que tu problema no se debería en teoría a la versión de .net ya que especificas que es la 4.8, en la web de donde saque esta información sobre las actualizaciones que están dando ese problema, también está la resolución a ese problema, la cual está detallada paso por paso, pero debes tocar el sistema operativo del servidor, habilitando y deshabilitando cosas o desinstalado, y todos sabemos que eso siempre trae problemas extras, pero puedes leerla para que te de una idea, si pones el texto entre comillas en google seguro llegues a ella. Saludos